# Selected value from database in DropDownList (not GridView)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I work in ASP NET 4.0 and C-sharp.

I have one form page **.aspx** with this DropDownList (*Inside is the ID*) and save the value **S** or **N** in the matching field in database :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Inside" runat="server" Width="100" CssClass="ddl_Class">
  <asp:ListItem Text="-------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="S" Value="S"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="N" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I need that when the value of field **Inside** in database is valid and is not null, in the DropDownList it's selected the value set in the database and disable the DropDownList.

I have tried this code in **.cs** page without success.

Anybody know how can I do that?

**code-behind**

```
InsideDB = dr["Inside"].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InsideDB.ToString()))
{
  Inside.Text = InsideDB.ToString();
  Inside.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
  Inside.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your full code ? Including your SqlCommand query. And what you're getting here ? . Any error ? or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SelectedValue` instead of `Text` property.

```
InsideDB = dr["Inside"].ToString();
Inside.Enabled = true;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InsideDB.ToString()))
{
  Inside.SelectedValue = InsideDB.ToString();
  Inside.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Inside.SelectedIndex = Inside.Items.IndexOf(Inside.Items.FindByText(InsideDB.ToString()));
```

instead of `Inside.Text = InsideDB.ToString();`

This assumes that you have an item with that text in the dropdownlist already.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post. But this may help others.

```
Inside.Items.FindByText(InsideDB.ToString()).Selected=true;
Inside.Enabled = false;
```